# How to allow same value using IN SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these excel file that have duplicate value **old_id** and I need to query based on **old id** to get **new_id** side by side because event old_id is the same but value of new_id in database might be different.

**Excel File**

```
old_id
1111
2222
3333 // same id value but different row
3333 // same id value but different row
4444
5555
```

When I tried to query based on old_id like below,

```
SELECT 
    new_id,
    old_id,
    status
FROM table  
    WHERE id in (
        '1111',
        '2222',
        '3333',
        '3333',
        '4444',
        '5555'
    )
order by id desc;
```

The output show like this. Only 5 records instead of 6 records

```
Output : 
new_id  old_id  status
1111    NEW101
2222    NEW201
3333    NEW301
4444    NEW401  
5555    NEW501
```

How can I achieve to show it in 6 records ? Is it possible ?

**Expected Output :**

```
  Output : 
        new_id  old_id  status
        1111    NEW101
        2222    NEW201
        3333    NEW301
        3333    NEW311
        4444    NEW401  
        5555    NEW501
```

Thanks

Comment: Please tell us a) if you're using MySQL 8+, and also 2) explain the numbering system in the output `old_id` column.  What happens if there are more than 100 duplicates for a given number?  This is not clear based on your small sample data set.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thank you for the reply. a) I'm using MySQL 5.7. b) output for old_id is from excel file. old_id is application_id actually and the format is number only.